# Centering and styling Bootstrap 4 navbar with custom color and spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

New to frontend development and trying to get acquainted with Twitter Bootstrap 4 and CSS with a mock nonprofit page. I really like how the [Auth0.com](https://auth0.com/) header nav looks and I'm trying to replicate it with my own logo, colors and link text.

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrk6tfoL/) capturing my best attempt but essentially the code I have is as follows:

**Excerpt from template.html -- see jsFiddle for full:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="margin:24px 0;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitbythecron/bootstrap-troubleshooting/main/dummy-logo.png" class="img-fluid mainlogo" alt="Responsive image">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Help</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Volunteer</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Find</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Support</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Always</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link red-button" href="javascript:void(0)">WATCH DEMO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign In</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link bordered" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**main.css:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.bordered {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.red-button {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #A81E30;
    background-color: #A81E30;
    color: beige;
}

.mainlogo {
    width: 35%;
}
```

When this runs in the browser, I get:

[image]

Several things here:

- above the navbar there is about ~10px of whitespace, and I'd like there to be none; I tried setting `<html>`'s `padding: 0px` but that does not seem to work
- the navbar background color is the BS4 default dark gray, but I'd like it to be the same color as the dark blue on my logo (`#001A31`)
- I would like to remove all padding from the navbar so that the height of the navbar is the same height as the logo
- just like the Auth0 navbar, I would like the header navbar to centered but with extra spacing between the logo and the first link ("*About*") and also the same extra space between the last `red-button` link ("*WATCH DEMO*") and the "*Sign In*" link

So I ask: what changes do I need to make to my HTML/CSS to accomplish my mock page's navbar looking like the Auth0 one, and how do I do all this while keeping the code responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `style="margin:24px 0;"` into your `<nav>` tag.

---

**Placements** in css acts **like a clock**. I mean, in order :

1. Top
2. Right
3. Bottom
4. Left

**Result :** `margin : top right bottom left;`

Or by pairs :

1. Top & bottom
2. Left & right

**Result :** `margin : top&bottom left&right;`

---

So your `style="margin:24px 0;"` should be **removed**, or **interverting** 24px with 0.
Because you are actually saying :

- Margin Top and Bottom = 24px
- Margin Left and Right = 0px

PS: It is a bad practice to add `style` directly in HTML. For testing purposes, I suggest you to use your **browser console**, because you can change css properties for each elements, and see what happens.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks @Devart (+1) -- any ideas about changing the background color from dark gray to match my logo's blue? And removing the padding around the logo so that the navbar is the same height as the logo?

Comment: In your browser, you have an util to pick up colors from images or dom elements.  Open your console browser (f12 for chrome). Then go to a color definition (like your background-color), click on the color, then click on the "picker icon" and then pick the color from your logo

Comment: Thanks again, but when I add `.navbar { background-color: #001A31; }` to my `main.css` it doesn't do anything...

Comment: Your navbar has the class `bg-dark` which set the `background-color:#343a40 !important` .  
The "!important" properties means "whatever color you set, I prefer this one". So try to remove your `bg-dark` class, or override the color by setting yours with `!important`properties too. The last "important" color called will be the displayed one !